# JQuery toggle a OL list with headings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle, anchor

I have an OL list that works as an accordion with jQuery toggle, and I also have a sidebar with anchor links linking to the OL list headings. I would like to make so that the anchor links link to and toggle open the respective headings.

Can someone help me add to this script so that when I click on the anchor link, the respective section div opens?

Thanks!!

```js
jQuery('#sections > li > div').hide();

jQuery('#sections > li > h2').click(function(e){
    
    e.preventDefault();
    // hide all div
    var $li = jQuery(this).parent();
    var $div = jQuery(this).parent().find('div');
    jQuery("#sections > li > div").not($div).hide();
    jQuery("#sections > li").not($li).removeClass('active');
    
    // here is what I want to do
    $div.toggle();
    $li.toggleClass('active');
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>In this Lesson:</h2>
<ol id="sections_list">
  <li><a href="#learning_objectives">Learning Objectives</a></li>
  <li><a href="#resources_provided_in_this_lesson">Resources provided in this lesson</a></li>
  <li><a href="#preparation">Preparation</a></li>
  <li><a href="#safety_notes">Safety notes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#background_information">Background information</a></li>
  <li><a href="#vocabulary">Vocabulary</a></li>
  <li><a href="#lesson_in_detail">Lesson in detail</a></li>
  <li><a href="#acknowledgements">Acknowledgements</a></li>
</ol>    

<ol id="sections">
  <li><h2 id="learning_objectives">Learning Objectives</h2>
    <div>Content...</div>
  </li>
  <li><h2 id="resources_provided_in_this_lesson">Resources provided in this lesson</h2>
    <div>Content...</div>
  </li>
  <li><h2 id="preparation">Preparation</h2>
    <div>Content...</div>
  </li>
  <li><h2 id="safety_notes">Safety notes</h2>
    <div>Content...</div>
  </li>
  <li><h2 id="background_information">Background information</h2>
    <div>Content...</div>
  </li>
  <li><h2 id="vocabulary">Vocabulary</h2>
    <div>Content...</div>
  </li>
  <li><h2 id="lesson_in_detail">Lesson in detail</h2>
    <div>Content...</div>
  </li>
  <li><h2 id="acknowledgements">Acknowledgements</h2>
    <div>Content...</div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the href of the anchors to trigger the clicks manually.

```
$('#sections_list li').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
  $(href).click();
})
```

```js
jQuery('#sections > li > div').hide();

jQuery('#sections > li > h2').click(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  // hide all div
  var $li = jQuery(this).parent();
  var $div = jQuery(this).parent().find('div');
  jQuery("#sections > li > div").not($div).hide();
  jQuery("#sections > li").not($li).removeClass('active');

  // here is what I want to do
  $div.toggle();
  $li.toggleClass('active');

});

$('#sections_list li').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
  $(href).click();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>In this Lesson:</h2>
<ol id="">
  <li><a href="#learning_objectives">Learning Objectives</a></li>
  <li><a href="#resources_provided_in_this_lesson">Resources provided in this lesson</a></li>
  <li><a href="#preparation">Preparation</a></li>
  <li><a href="#safety_notes">Safety notes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#background_information">Background information</a></li>
  <li><a href="#vocabulary">Vocabulary</a></li>
  <li><a href="#lesson_in_detail">Lesson in detail</a></li>
  <li><a href="#acknowledgements">Acknowledgements</a></li>
</ol>    

<ol id="sections">
  <li><h2 id="learning_objectives">Learning Objectives</h2>
    <div>Content...</div>
  </li>
  <li><h2 id="resources_provided_in_this_lesson">Resources provided in this lesson</h2>
    <div>Content...</div>
  </li>
  <li><h2 id="preparation">Preparation</h2>
    <div>Content...</div>
  </li>
  <li><h2 id="safety_notes">Safety notes</h2>
    <div>Content...</div>
  </li>
  <li><h2 id="background_information">Background information</h2>
    <div>Content...</div>
  </li>
  <li><h2 id="vocabulary">Vocabulary</h2>
    <div>Content...</div>
  </li>
  <li><h2 id="lesson_in_detail">Lesson in detail</h2>
    <div>Content...</div>
  </li>
  <li><h2 id="acknowledgements">Acknowledgements</h2>
    <div>Content...</div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Hi Arun, thanks for the reply.
Does this code open (toggle) the respective section? It doesn't seem so, on my end. Can you confirm? Thanks!

Comment: That actually worked! Awesome. Except that the anchor itself stops working for some reason.  I'm trying to add this code to it, but isn't working: `$('#sections_list li').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
});`